# How to set mailbox icon from bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my page screenshot http://s30.postimg.org/44jynnz35/Untitled_2.png

html:

```
    <div id="social-bar">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Open-Source-Hacker/181710458567630">
            <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
            <span>Facebook</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/moo9000">
            <i class="icon icon-twitter"></i>
            <span>Twitter</span>
        </a>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/103323677227728078543/">
            <i class="icon icon-google-plus"></i>
            <span>Google Plus</span>
        </a>
        <a href="http://opensourcehacker.com/">
            <i class="icon icon-rss"></i>
            <span>Blog</span>
        </a>

       </div>
```

I have been created social links with social icons, I took source code from this link https://github.com/miohtama/FontAwesome-and-Bootstrap-social-icons-example/

I need one more link and icon, that is `mailbox`.

So i added code like this,

```
   <a href="http://opensourcehacker.com/">
                <i class="icon icon-gmail"></i>
                <span>Email</span>
   </a>
```

But i m not sure for mail box icon code,

I have 3 files,

```
1. <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

2. <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

3. <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So may i know, exact code for mailbox icon or where can i take?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `icon-envelope`

```
<a href="http://opensourcehacker.com/"><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i><span>Email</span>   </a>
```

Since you are using older version of fontawesome, some icons may be missing from the file. Try using this updated library : http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css instead of older one.

Comment: thanks a lot... i searched for a long time,, but i didn't get.. may i know how you search?

Comment: and also, you know for youtube play?

Comment: The CSS you are using is a modified fontawesome. You can get the complete list here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/ . Just make sure you replace "fa" class with "icon" , even the text too. So for instance if you have "fa-envelope" for mail icon, in your case, it should be "icon-envelope". youtube: "icon-youtube"

Comment: @rishiga It appears that the fontawesome version is not latest. It's 3.0.2. Check the cheatsheet for this version here: http://www.thinkgeek.com/tools/font-awesome/index.shtml . You may have to update fontawesome